# uncaught ReferenceError: tgl is not defined

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I dont really know what is causing the error since I'm new to JavaScript. I've referenced the variable in the header with js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {          
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function date(start, end, alldays){
      $("#BookingModal").modal('toggle');
      var tgl=moment(start).format('DD-MM-YYYY')
    }
  });
  
  calendar.render();
});
```

And when I want to use the variable in the body of the html, it throws the error:

> uncaught ReferenceError: tgl is not defined

```
<h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel"> <script type="text/javascript">document.write(tgl)</script></h1>
```

Comment: The `document.write` you have is executed while parsing the document... And the script you have in the `head` is executed after because of the `DOMContentLoaded` event handler. -- anyway, it is defined in a callback function of the calendar which is executed when the calendar `select` event fires...

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you are attempting, because you question definitely is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: what i'm trying to make is a calendar with fullcalendar.io, and what i'm trying to do is when you click on a date it opens up the bootstrap modal where you can write notes. in the modal title i want to show the start date for the note but i'm getting the error. how can i fix this?

Comment: You probably need to set the modal title when it opens then... The is [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content) about it. It will probably look like `$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  modal.find('.modal-title').text(tgl)
})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modal title you whish to have is dynamic based on the calendar cell that was clicked.

So you have to wait for the user to click on a calendar cell to know what is the `startDate` provided in this `select` callback.

The code below will be exectuted on page load while parsing the HTML...
Long before the rest of your code that will execute after `DOMContentLoaded` has fired.

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(tgl)</script>
```

The events are firing in this order and that is how `tgl` should be used in each of them:

1. `DOMContentLoaded` -- `tgl` is declared
2. FullCalendar's `select` -- `tgl` value is setted
3. `show.bs.modal` -- `tgl` value is used

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // Have the tgl variable at global scope
  let tgl;

  // On modal open, set the modal title
  $("#BookingModal").on("show.bs.modal", function (event) {
    $("#BookingModal").find(".modal-title").text(tgl);
  });

  // FulCalendar
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    selectable: true,
    select: function date(start, end, alldays) {
      // Set tgl here
      tgl = moment(start.startStr).format("DD-MM-YYYY");

      // Open modal
      $("#BookingModal").modal("show");
    }
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.0.2/index.global.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="calendar"></div>

<div class="modal fade" id="BookingModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">This title will be replaced</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Some modal body here...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/VwBPXqa?editors=0011)

Also, notice I used `start.startStr` to pass to moment.js. You can console log that `start` object of FullCalendar to understand why.